# How to add cmd+` shortcut in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

In VS Code on Mac OS, the system shortcut for `View: Toggle Terminal` is `` ctrl+` `` (control backtick).

I want to add `` cmd+` `` (command backtick) combination because I keep pressing that on external keyboard, but the *Keyboard Shortcuts* UI screen doesn't detect that combination.

Is there a trick how to add it?

Comment: Upvote the issue https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/178351

Answer (score 1):

Sure! If you are on the *Keyboard Shortcuts* screen (`cmd+k,s`), open the JSON file by clicking the top right corner icon with curly arrow (see screenshot): [image: open json]

In the `keybindings.json` file, add the shortcut manually:

```json
  },
  {
    "key": "cmd+`",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.toggleTerminal",
    "when": "terminal.active"
  }
]
```